# scipy minimize not finding solution

Tags: python, scipy, scipy-optimize-minimize

I'm trying to solve a set of equations using scipy.minimize, however I'm not getting satisfatory results, so maybe I'm gettting something wrong.
I want to solve the following system of equations.

```
12.25 * (x + y * 2.2 + z * 4.84) - 8.17437483750257 = 0
12.25 * (x + y * 3.1 + z * 9.61) - 21.9317236606432 = 0
12.25 * (x + y * 4   + z * 16)   - 107.574834524443 = 0
```

Using Wolfram Alpha I get the answers

```
x=22.626570068753, y=-17.950683342597, z=3.6223614029055
```

Which indeed solve the system of equations, giving a residual error of

```
9.407585821463726e-12
```

Now using scipy.minimize I do:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
from scipy.optimize import minimize

def my_func(p):
    points = [8.17437483750257, 21.9317236606432, 107.574834524443]
    h1 = abs(12.25 * (p[0] + p[1] * 2.2 + p[2] * 4.84) - points[0])
    h2 = abs(12.25 * (p[0] + p[1] * 3.1 + p[2] * 9.61) - points[1])
    h3 = abs(12.25 * (p[0] + p[1] * 4   + p[2] * 16)   - points[2])
    return h1 + h2 + h3

ini = np.array([22, -15, 5])   # Initial points close to solution
res = minimize(my_func, ini)
print(res)



  fun: 1.4196640741924451
  hess_inv: array([[ 20.79329103, -14.63447889,   2.36145776],
   [-14.63447889,  10.30037625,  -1.66214485],
   [  2.36145776,  -1.66214485,   0.26822135]])
  jac: array([ 12.25      ,  60.02499545, 254.43249989])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
  nfev: 261
  nit: 8
  njev: 64
  status: 2
  success: False
    x: array([ 21.39197235, -17.08623345,   3.48344393])
```

First, It says success=False and second it finds solutions that are not optimal.

Why having initial values that are close to the optimal solution it fails to find those solutions.

Is it something wrong with the definition of the optimizer?

Tried running it giving initial values of [0,0,0] and it just gives awful results

```
ini = np.array([0, 0, 0])   # Initial points close to solution
res = minimize(my_func, ini)
print(res)

fun: 73.66496363902732
 hess_inv: array([[ 0.98461683, -0.04223651, -0.1207056 ],
       [-0.04223651,  0.88596592, -0.31885642],
       [-0.1207056 , -0.31885642,  0.13448927]])
      jac: array([ 12.25      ,  15.92499924, -18.98750019])
  message: 'Desired error not necessarily achieved due to precision loss.'
     nfev: 164
      nit: 1
     njev: 40
   status: 2
  success: False
        x: array([0.02901304, 0.08994042, 0.29448233])
```

Note: I don't want to use `fsolve` to find the solutions, but `minimize`.
The reason is that my real problem involves having more equations than unknowns, so at the end I want a solution that minimizes the errors of all this equations.
However since it was not giving good results, I wanted to first test on an easy problem for which an exact solution exists. But even in this case it doesn't work.
Once I make it work for this problem I'll expand it adding more equations.

Comment: Your system is linear, why do you want to use a nonlinear optimization approach rather than just solving it using linear algebra???

Comment: I edited the question. At the end I want an optimizer for a system with more equations than unknowns. The system will still be linear but the solution will not be exact, it will just be a minimum error. How can I get a linear minimizer to solve this problem?

Comment: This sounds like the generalized method of moments. Does squaring the differences instead of using absolute values help? E.g. `h1 =(12.25 * (p[0] + p[1] * 2.2 + p[2] * 4.84) - points[0])**2`

Comment: @ForceBru. Yes! I changed the sum for the square and it gives the exact result. Thanks. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki If you have more equations than unknowns, but the system is still linear, then it can still be solved using linear algebra, the solution is to use linear least-squares, as in f.ex. numpy.linalg.lstsq

Comment: @Vinzent Ok, thanks, I'll try this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ...my real problem involves having more equations than unknowns, so at the end I want a solution that minimizes the errors of all this equations

This sounds a lot like the problem solved in the generalized method of moments (GMM), where you also have more equations than unknowns.

Problems of this kind are usually solved using least squares. Suppose your whole system looks like this:

```
h1(x, y, z) = 0
h2(x, y, z) = 0
h3(x, y, z) = 0
h4(x, y, z) = 0
```

It has 3 unknowns and 4 equations. Then your objective function will be:

```
F(x, y, z) = H(x, y, z)' * W * H(x, y, z)
```

- `H(x, y, z)` is the vector of all `hj(x, y, z)` above
- `H(x, y, z)'` is its transpose
- `W` is the weighting matrix

If `W` is the identity matrix, you get the least squares objective function. Then, `F(x, y, z)` is a quadratic form (basically a parabola in multiple dimensions), which should be simple to optimize because it's convex and smooth.

Your code uses absolute values like `h1 = abs(12.25 * (p[0] + p[1] * 2.2 + p[2] * 4.84) - points[0])`, but `abs` can be difficult to differentiate near the origin, yet that's exactly where your optimum lies, since you essentially want `h1` to equal zero.

You can approximate the absolute value function by squaring the error:

```
h1 =(12.25 * (p[0] + p[1] * 2.2 + p[2] * 4.84) - points[0])**2
```

This results in basically the same approach as the GMM (or least squares) and gives you a function that's easy to optimize since the square is smooth near the origin.

Comment: Yes, at the end I ended using least squares and I'm getting better results than using the scipy non linear optimizer.

Answer (score 1):

Optimisation problems (and solvers) usually benefit from a well behaved (smooth) "optimisation surface". When you use the `abs` function, it creates a "choppy" surface, with points were the derivatives are not continuous.

If instead of using `abs` you use a quadratic function (that has the same effect), you get a solution close to what you expect. Just change `my_func` to:

```py
def my_func(p):
    points = [8.17437483750257, 21.9317236606432, 107.574834524443]
    h1 = (12.25 * (p[0] + p[1] * 2.2 + p[2] * 4.84) - points[0])**2
    h2 = (12.25 * (p[0] + p[1] * 3.1 + p[2] * 9.61) - points[1])**2
    h3 = (12.25 * (p[0] + p[1] * 4   + p[2] * 16)   - points[2])**2
    return h1 + h2 + h3
```

What I got is:

```
      fun: 8.437863292878727e-10
 hess_inv: array([[ 0.64753863, -0.43474506,  0.06909179],
       [-0.43474506,  0.29487798, -0.04722923],
       [ 0.06909179, -0.04722923,  0.00761762]])
      jac: array([-6.26698693e-12,  6.22490927e-10, -5.11716516e-10])
  message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nfev: 55
      nit: 7
     njev: 11
   status: 0
  success: True
        x: array([ 22.62653789, -17.95066124,   3.62235782])
```